# Find out Provider name with whois in bash

Tags: mysql, bash, provider, whois

**TL;DR**

I would like to extract the Provider, range Start, range End and the name of the provider from the output of `whois` in an automated way, but that output varies by provider, so I would like help extracting those three pieces of information for any provider.

**Details**

I've got a list of IPs. I want to check their provider for each IP with the help of whois for my script and want to pipe it to a Database using mysql.

I want to fill a mySQL Table with the ipranges of the provider but only if the Range of the Provider is already there.

i.e. `IP=187.187.187.187` `whois $IP` and then get the Providername and the Range of segment but only if i don't already have it in my Table

I got a plan that it should look something like this:

```
function ip2dec ...
function dec2ip ...

function awhois (){ ... 
     THEPROVIDER=$(whois $1 | grep PROVIDER) #<- i don't know how to grep 
     THERANGESTART=$(whois $1 | grep START) #<- i don't know how to grep
     THERANGEENDING=$(whois $1 | grep END) #<- i don't know how to grep
}

while read line; do 
    DECIP=`ip2dec $line`
    if [[ ! $(mysql -u$THEUSER -p$PASSWORD -h$THEHOST -e "select iprangestart, iprangeend from $DATABASE.$TABLE where $DECIP BETWEEN iprangestart and iprangeend" 2>/dev/null) ]];
        then
        awhois $line
        mysql -u$THEUSER -p$PASSWORD -h$THEHOST -e 
           "INSERT INTO $DATABASE.$TABLE (iprangestart, iprangeend, provider) 
                VALUES ( \"$THERANGESTART\", \"$THERANGEENDING\", \"$THEPROVIDER\")" 2>/dev/null
    fi
done < data/allips
```

But i don't really know how to grep the provider and the range since it has a different pattern from provider to provider

Comment: You're very close, that's how you define a function in bash. Is this not working for you? Can you add to your question what output you get?

Comment: Here's what looks like a good tutorial: https://linuxize.com/post/bash-functions/

Comment: In fact, I just did some tests, and your function should work as written and as used.

Comment: @joanis sorry, my english isnt good at all. I had a different questing in mind. My Problem was the grep since it is different from provider to provider inside whois. Still thank you :)

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for updating the question, then! I don't have easy access to whois right now, so I won't be able to help you with that, sorry.

Comment: This may help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/342489/327696

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave it up after trying alot of different ways to get the provider name with the help of whois. And tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958360/how-can-i-find-my-internet-service-provider-isp-using-a-bash-script) instead.

I had to use wget since curl did'nt give me anything useful.

This is the final result:

```
function ip2dec(){ # Convert an IPv4 IP number to its decimal equivalent.
      declare -i a b c d;
      IFS=. read a b c d <<<"$1";
      echo "$(((a<<24)+(b<<16)+(c<<8)+d))";
}

while read ipadd; do 
    DECIP=`ip2dec $ipadd`
    if [[ $(mysql -N -u$THEUSER -p$PASSWORD -h$THEHOST -e "select providername from $DATABASE.$TABLE where $DECIP >= providerrangestart and $DECIP <= providerrangeende" 2>/dev/null| wc -l) -eq 0 ]];
    then
        INET=$(whois $ipadd | egrep "inetnum")
        NETRAN=$(whois $ipadd | egrep "netrange")
        ISPP=`wget https://www.whoismyisp.org/ip/$ipadd 2>/dev/null`
        THEPROVIDER=`cat $ISPP | grep -oP -m1 '(?<=isp">).*(?=</p)' | cut -c -31`
        if [[ $(echo "$THEPROVIDER" | egrep -i 'D2VODAFONE|Arcor|Vodafone D2') ]]; then 
            THEPROVIDER="Vodafone GmbH"
        elif [[ $(echo "$THEPROVIDER" | egrep -i "Telefonica|Telefonica O2") ]]; then
            THEPROVIDER="Deutsche Telekom AG"
        elif [[ $(echo "$THEPROVIDER" | egrep -i "1&1 Versatel Deutschland GmbH|1&1 Internet SE") ]]; then
            THEPROVIDER="1&1 GmbH"
        fi

        if [[ $INET ]];then 
            echo "new dump"
            THERANGESTART=`echo $INET | awk '{print $2}'`
            DECRANGESTART=`ip2dec $RANGESTART`
            echo "Rangestart: $DECRANGESTART"
            RANGEEND=`echo $INET | awk '{print $4}'`
            DECRANGEEND=`ip2dec $RANGEEND`
            echo "Rangeend: $RANGEEND"
            echo "Provider: $THEPROVIDER"
            echo ""
            mysql -u$THEUSER -p$PASSWORD -h$THEHOST -e "INSERT INTO $DATABASE.$TABLE (providerrangestart, providerrangeende, providername) VALUES ( \"$DECRANGESTART\", \"$DECRANGEEND\", \"$THEPROVIDER\")" 2>/dev/null 

        elif [[ $NETRAN ]]; then
            echo "new dump"
            THERANGESTART=`echo $NETRAN | awk '{print $2}'`
            DECRANGESTART=`ip2dec $RANGESTART`
            echo "Rangestart: $RANGESTART"
            RANGEEND=`echo $NETRAN | awk '{print $4}'`
            DECRANGEEND=`ip2dec $RANGEEND`
            echo "Rangeend: $RANGEEND"
            echo "Provider: $THEPROVIDER"
            echo ""
            mysql -u$THEUSER -p$PASSWORD -h$THEHOST -e "INSERT INTO $DATABASE.$TABLE (providerrangestart, providerrangeende, providername) VALUES ( \"$DECRANGESTART\", \"$DECRANGEEND\", \"$THEPROVIDER\")" 2>/dev/null            

        else 
            echo "Failed to optain ISP and IP-Range" 
            echo -e "$ipadd \n"
        fi
        rm $ipadd
    fi
done < data/allips
rm data/allips
```